# Master page throws error when code is inserted

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a master page that throws an error on content pages when the following line of code is inserted into the master page. It will not let me enter design mode.

```
<script src='<%= CacheHelper.Fingerprint("/assets/scripts/app.min.js") %>' />
```

However, the following line of code doesn't throw an error. I've tweaked the quotes, added a type etc, but it still refuses to play ball.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<%= CacheHelper.Fingerprint("/assets/styles/app.min.css") %>' />
```

I'm using VS2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trawling, trying and testing for a few hours I can categorically say that 99% of the answers to similar questions do not work.

The answer I found that did work was to replace the end tag `'/>` with `'></script>'` - after this Visual Studio started behaving.